# Passing Arguments to classes extending the service class Java

Tags: javafx, service, concurrency

I was wondering if there was a way to pass arguments the a class extending the Service class from the Javafx concurrent package. I would like ProteinariumThread to take in a String argument like ClusterID seen below:

```
public class ProteinariumThread extends Service<String>{
    String ClusterID = "q";
    @Override


    protected Task<String> createTask(){

        return new Task<String>() {
            @Override
            protected String call() throws Exception {
                updateMessage("Running Proteinarium");
                System.out.println("Asleep");
                ProteinariumRun.PRun(ClusterID);
                System.out.println("Woke Up");
                String woke = "Woke Up";
                return woke;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Currently in order to run this background task I use the following bit of code:

```
final ProteinariumThread service = new ProteinariumThread();
service.start();
```

This however does not allow me to take in a String argument. Is there anyway to make it that service.start() is able to take in String arguments so that String variable ClusterID can come from outside of the ProteinariumThread class?

```
final ProteinariumThread service = new ProteinariumThread();
service.start(ClusterID);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to give your service class a constructor and/or method which accepts the necessary argument. As services are meant to be reusable, it'd probably be best to allow configuration throughout the service's lifetime by exposing a property:

```java
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.concurrent.Service;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class ProteinariumService extends Service<String> {

  private final StringProperty clusterId = new SimpleStringProperty(this, "clusterId");
  public final void setClusterId(String clusterId) { this.clusterId.set(clusterId); }
  public final String getClusterId() { return clusterId.get(); }
  public final StringProperty clusterIdProperty() { return clusterId; }

  public ProteinariumService() {}

  public ProteinariumService(String clusterId) {
    setClusterId(clusterId);
  }

  @Override
  protected Task<String> createTask() {
    return new Task<>() {

        final String clusterId = getClusterId(); // cache configuration

        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {
            ...
        }
    };
  }
}
```

It's important you copy the needed state from the service to the task since the task is executed on a background thread.

Then when you need to change the cluster ID you just do:

```java
// or bind the property to something in the UI (e.g. a TextField)
theService.setClusterId(newClusterId);
theService.start();
```

If you really want to be able to do that in one line you can always define an overload for `start` in your service class:

```java
public void start(String clusterId) {
  setClusterId(clusterId):
  start();
}
```